# Could someone explain these lines of code

Tags: apex

Im getting the following error

> GroepsLidTrigger : GroepsLidTrigger: execution of AfterUpdate caused
>   by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
>   Class.GroupsUtil.sendEmailAfterUpdate: line 103, column 1
>   Class.GroepslidUtil.entry: line 58, column 1 Trigger.GroepsLidTrigger:
>   line 3, column 1

line 103 is the first if line here

```
if (templates.containsKey('InactivatedGroup')) {
    templateName = templates.get('InactivatedGroup').Email_template__c;
}
```

I assume templates.containsKey does not heave the field value InactivatedGroup but im not sure if the get is throwing the error. So could someone explain what these 2 lines do especially `templates.get('InactivatedGroup').Email_template__c`

Comment: how are you getting the field Email_template__c in the map? Also are you sure you are instantiating the map?

Comment: You are looking in your Map 'templates' for the value linked to the key 'InactivatedGroup'. Then assigning the value of its custom field Email_template__c to your variable templateName.

Comment: The developer forgot to initialize the map, as @Eric says. It was probably a lazy-initialization that got skipped or something. In other words, this line crashing isn't the cause of bad logic, simply the symptom. You'll need to read the code backwards to see how it's supposed to be initialized and populated, and fix that code instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is being thrown

```
if (templates.containsKey('InactivatedGroup')) {
```

because `templates` is **null** and it is being dereferenced by performing `.containsKay`

This will cause it:

```
Map<String,Object[]> templates;
if (templates.containsKey('InactivatedGroup')) {
```

Where this not throw a NPE as the map has been initialized

```
Map<String,Object[]> templates = New Map<String,Object[]>;
if (templates.containsKey('InactivatedGroup')) {
```

Your code is basically:

```
//Check to see if the Map contains the key so the value can be obtained
if (templates.containsKey('InactivatedGroup')) {
    //Grab the `Email_Template__c` value from the item associated with the key and assign it to the templateName. If we did not do the check above there is a potential for a NPE if the key does not exist
    templateName = templates.get('InactivatedGroup').Email_template__c;
}
```

Anytime you `.` a property/variable it is a good practice to ensure that it is not null either by checking for the key existing previously or checking specifically to ensure it is not null.